# Maya API removeChild makes the child desapear from outliner?

Tags: python, maya

I am running this code below, and when I run the last line, the locator B desapeared from outliner… how can parent the locator B to the world, keeping the locator in the outliner?

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as new_om

def getMObject(node):
    selList = new_om.MSelectionList()
    selList.add(node)
    return selList.getDependNode(0)

cmds.spaceLocator(name="A")
cmds.spaceLocator(name="B")

A_MObj = getMObject("A")
B_MObj = getMObject("B")

parentNode_B_to_A = new_om.MFnDagNode(A_MObj)

parentNode_B_to_A.addChild(B_MObj)

parentNode_B_to_A.removeChild(B_MObj)
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add `B` back to the *world* node. In your case `A` and `B` are directly parented under *world*, so you can query and use `A`'s parent:

```
...
parentNode_B_to_A.removeChild(B_MObj)

world_obj = parentNode_B_to_A.parent(0)
world_node = new_om.MFnDagNode(world_obj)
world_node.addChild(B_MObj)
```